# Set background Color and space/padding for the LineChartData Label with ios-charts

Tags: ios, charts

How can i set  background Color and space/padding for the LineChartData Label?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMG6w.png)

Here is my Code:

```
            let chartData = LineChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
            chartData.setValueTextColor(#colorLiteral(red: 0.8531932235, green: 0.5181117058, blue: 0.5039681792, alpha: 1))
            chartData.setValueFont(.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use textColor property as below:

```
yourChart.legend.textColor = UIColor.yourDesiredColor
```

Comment: I want to change background color not the textcolor.Plz click on image description for details